# Calculating gradient with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, gradient

I really can not understand what `numpy.gradient` function does and how to use it for computation of *multivariable function gradient*.

For example, I have such a function:

```
def func(q, chi, delta):
    return q * chi * delta
```

I need to compute it's 3-dimensional gradient (in other words, I want to compute partial derivatives with respect to all variables (q, chi, delta)).

How can I calculate this gradient using NumPy?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is, that numpy can't give you the derivatives directly and you have two options:

**With NUMPY**

What you essentially have to do, is to define a grid in three dimension and to evaluate the function on this grid. Afterwards you feed this table of function values to `numpy.gradient` to get an array with the numerical derivative for every dimension (variable).

Example from [here](http://mindseye.no/2011/09/12/calculating-the-gradient-in-python/):

```
from numpy import *

x,y,z = mgrid[-100:101:25., -100:101:25., -100:101:25.]

V = 2*x**2 + 3*y**2 - 4*z # just a random function for the potential

Ex,Ey,Ez = gradient(V)
```

**Without NUMPY**

You could also calculate the derivative yourself by using the [centered difference quotient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficients).
[image: centered difference quotient]

This is essentially, what `numpy.gradient` [is doing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) for every point of your predefined grid.

Comment: Thanks,Stefan! In fact I understand how to compute derivatives manualy (without any framework), but I was not able to understand how np.gradient works. Previously I'd used for this purpose combination of  C++ with gsl, but this approach requires too much coding.

Comment: To be precise, the formula is what `numpy.diff` does; `numpy.gradient` is similar but has special behaviour at boundaries.

Comment: @Mark: `numpy.gradient` is much more like like this formula (centered difference quotient with $+\Delta x$ and $-\Delta x$) than `numpy.diff`

Comment: They are both quite similar. `gradient` indeed uses the central difference *at* the grid points, which is similar, but treats the boundaries differently. `diff` could be said to get the central difference in the middle *between* the grid point (with delta half a grid spacing), and doesn't treat boundaries specially but just makes the gradient grid 1 point smaller. They both follow the expression, but with different evaluation points and deltas, and with different boundary behaviour. Since the answer doesn't mention how to treat any of that, I guess it's subjective which is more similar...

Answer (score 14):

Numpy and Scipy are for numerical calculations. Since you want to calculate the gradient of an analytical function, you have to use the [Sympy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html) package which supports symbolic mathematics. Differentiation is explained [here](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/mpmath/calculus/differentiation.html) (you can actually use it in the web console in the left bottom corner).

You can install Sympy under Ubuntu with

```
sudo apt-get install python-sympy
```

or under any Linux distribution with [pip](http://filon.us/slava/?p=189)

```
sudo pip install sympy
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`scipy.optimize.approx_fprime`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.approx_fprime.html)

```
f = lambda x: x**2
approx_fprime(np.array([2]), f, epsilon=1e-6)  # array([ 4.000001])
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy doesn't directly support gradient calculations without creating an entire grid of points.  Instead, I would use [autodifferentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) 
See https://code.activestate.com/recipes/580610-auto-differentiation/ for how to do it in Python.

Comment: Can you post the relevant bits from the link that directly answers the question?