# Numerical gradient for nonlinear function in numpy/scipy

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, numerical-methods

I'm trying to implement an numerical gradient calculation in numpy to be used as the callback function for the gradient in cyipopt. My understanding of the numpy gradient function is that it should return the gradient calculated at a point based on a [finite different approximation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078818/calculating-gradient-with-numpy).

I don't understand how I would able to implement the gradient of a nonlinear function with this module. The sample problem given appears to be a linear function.

```
>>> f = np.array([1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16], dtype=np.float)
>>> np.gradient(f)
array([ 1. ,  1.5,  2.5,  3.5,  4.5,  5. ])
>>> np.gradient(f, 2)
array([ 0.5 ,  0.75,  1.25,  1.75,  2.25,  2.5 ])
```

My code snippet is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

# Hock & Schittkowski test problem #40
x = np.mgrid[0.75:0.85:0.01, 0.75:0.8:0.01, 0.75:0.8:0.01, 0.75:0.8:0.01]
# target is evaluation at x = [0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8]
f = -x[0] * x[1] * x[2] * x[3]
g = np.gradient(f)

print g
```

The other downside of this is that I have to evaluate x at several points (and it returns the gradient at several points)
Is there a better option in numpy/scipy for the gradient to be numerically evaluated at a **single** point so I can implement this as a callback function?

Answer (score 6):

#### First of all, some warnings:

- numerical-optimization is hard to do right
- [ipopt](https://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/) is very complex software

  - combining ipopt with numerical-differentiation sounds like you are asking for trouble, but that depends on your problem of course
  - ipopt is almost always based on [automatic-differentiation tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) and not [numerical-differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation)!

#### And some more:

- as this is a complex task and the state of python + ipopt is not as nice as in some other languages ([julia](https://julialang.org/) + [JuMP](https://jump.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for example), it's a bit of work

#### And some alternatives:

- use [pyomo](http://www.pyomo.org/) which wraps ipopt and has automatic-differentiation
- use [casadi](https://github.com/casadi/casadi) which also wraps ipopt and has automatic-differentiation
- use [autograd](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd) to automatically calculate gradients on a subset of numpy-code

  - then use cyipopt to add those
- [scipy.minimize with solvers SLSQP or COBYLA](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) which *can do everything for you* (SLSQP can use equality and inequality constraints; COBYLA only inequality-constraints, where emulating equality-constraints by `x >= y` + `x <= y` *can* work)

#### Approaching your task with your tools

Your complete example-problem is defined in [Test Examples for Nonlinear Programming Codes](http://www.ai7.uni-bayreuth.de/test_problem_coll.pdf):

[image]

Here is some code, based on numerical-differentiation, solving your test-problem, including the official setup (function, gradients, start-point, bounds, ...)

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sps
import ipopt
from scipy.optimize import approx_fprime


class Problem40(object):
    """ # Hock & Schittkowski test problem #40
            Basic structure  follows:
            - cyipopt example from https://pythonhosted.org/ipopt/tutorial.html#defining-the-problem
            - which follows ipopt's docs from: https://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node22.html
            Changes:
            - numerical-diff using scipy for function & constraints
            - removal of hessian-calculation
              - we will use limited-memory approximation
                - ipopt docs: https://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node31.html
              - (because i'm too lazy to reason about the math; lagrange and co.)
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.num_diff_eps = 1e-8  # maybe tuning needed!

    def objective(self, x):
        # callback for objective
        return -np.prod(x)  # -x1 x2 x3 x4

    def constraint_0(self, x):
        return np.array([x[0]**3 + x[1]**2 -1])

    def constraint_1(self, x):
        return np.array([x[0]**2 * x[3] - x[2]])

    def constraint_2(self, x):
        return np.array([x[3]**2 - x[1]])

    def constraints(self, x):
        # callback for constraints
        return np.concatenate([self.constraint_0(x),
                               self.constraint_1(x),
                               self.constraint_2(x)])

    def gradient(self, x):
        # callback for gradient
        return approx_fprime(x, self.objective, self.num_diff_eps)

    def jacobian(self, x):
        # callback for jacobian
        return np.concatenate([
            approx_fprime(x, self.constraint_0, self.num_diff_eps),
            approx_fprime(x, self.constraint_1, self.num_diff_eps),
            approx_fprime(x, self.constraint_2, self.num_diff_eps)])

    def hessian(self, x, lagrange, obj_factor):
        return False  # we will use quasi-newton approaches to use hessian-info

    # progress callback
    def intermediate(
            self,
            alg_mod,
            iter_count,
            obj_value,
            inf_pr,
            inf_du,
            mu,
            d_norm,
            regularization_size,
            alpha_du,
            alpha_pr,
            ls_trials
            ):

        print("Objective value at iteration #%d is - %g" % (iter_count, obj_value))

# Remaining problem definition; still following official source:
# http://www.ai7.uni-bayreuth.de/test_problem_coll.pdf

# start-point -> infeasible
x0 = [0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8]

# variable-bounds -> empty => np.inf-approach deviates from cyipopt docs!
lb = [-np.inf, -np.inf, -np.inf, -np.inf]
ub = [np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf]

# constraint bounds -> c == 0 needed -> both bounds = 0
cl = [0, 0, 0]
cu = [0, 0, 0]

nlp = ipopt.problem(
            n=len(x0),
            m=len(cl),
            problem_obj=Problem40(),
            lb=lb,
            ub=ub,
            cl=cl,
            cu=cu
            )

# IMPORTANT: need to use limited-memory / lbfgs here as we didn't give a valid hessian-callback
nlp.addOption(b'hessian_approximation', b'limited-memory')
x, info = nlp.solve(x0)
print(x)
print(info)

# CORRECT RESULT & SUCCESSFUL STATE
```

Output:

```
******************************************************************************
This program contains Ipopt, a library for large-scale nonlinear optimization.
 Ipopt is released as open source code under the Eclipse Public License (EPL).
         For more information visit http://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt
******************************************************************************

This is Ipopt version 3.12.8, running with linear solver mumps.
NOTE: Other linear solvers might be more efficient (see Ipopt documentation).

Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:       12
Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:        0
Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:        0

Total number of variables............................:        4
                     variables with only lower bounds:        0
                variables with lower and upper bounds:        0
                     variables with only upper bounds:        0
Total number of equality constraints.................:        3
Total number of inequality constraints...............:        0
        inequality constraints with only lower bounds:        0
   inequality constraints with lower and upper bounds:        0
        inequality constraints with only upper bounds:        0

Objective value at iteration #0 is - -0.4096
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
   0 -4.0960000e-01 2.88e-01 2.53e-02   0.0 0.00e+00    -  0.00e+00 0.00e+00   0
Objective value at iteration #1 is - -0.255391
   1 -2.5539060e-01 1.28e-02 2.98e-01 -11.0 2.51e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
Objective value at iteration #2 is - -0.249299
   2 -2.4929898e-01 8.29e-05 3.73e-01 -11.0 7.77e-03    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
Objective value at iteration #3 is - -0.25077
   3 -2.5076955e-01 1.32e-03 3.28e-01 -11.0 2.46e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
Objective value at iteration #4 is - -0.250025
   4 -2.5002535e-01 4.06e-05 1.93e-02 -11.0 4.65e-03    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
Objective value at iteration #5 is - -0.25
   5 -2.5000038e-01 6.57e-07 1.70e-04 -11.0 5.46e-04    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
Objective value at iteration #6 is - -0.25
   6 -2.5000001e-01 2.18e-08 2.20e-06 -11.0 9.69e-05    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
Objective value at iteration #7 is - -0.25
   7 -2.5000000e-01 3.73e-12 4.42e-10 -11.0 1.27e-06    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1

Number of Iterations....: 7

                                   (scaled)                 (unscaled)
Objective...............:  -2.5000000000225586e-01   -2.5000000000225586e-01
Dual infeasibility......:   4.4218750883118219e-10    4.4218750883118219e-10
Constraint violation....:   3.7250202922223252e-12    3.7250202922223252e-12
Complementarity.........:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Overall NLP error.......:   4.4218750883118219e-10    4.4218750883118219e-10


Number of objective function evaluations             = 8
Number of objective gradient evaluations             = 8
Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 8
Number of inequality constraint evaluations          = 0
Number of equality constraint Jacobian evaluations   = 8
Number of inequality constraint Jacobian evaluations = 0
Number of Lagrangian Hessian evaluations             = 0
Total CPU secs in IPOPT (w/o function evaluations)   =      0.016
Total CPU secs in NLP function evaluations           =      0.000

EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.
[ 0.79370053  0.70710678  0.52973155  0.84089641]
{'x': array([ 0.79370053,  0.70710678,  0.52973155,  0.84089641]), 'g': array([  3.72502029e-12,  -3.93685085e-13,   5.86974913e-13]), 'obj_val': -0.25000000000225586, 'mult_g': array([ 0.49999999, -0.47193715,  0.35355339]), 'mult_x_L': array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]), 'mult_x_U': array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]), 'status': 0, 'status_msg': b'Algorithm terminated successfully at a locally optimal point, satisfying the convergence tolerances (can be specified by options).'}
```

#### Remarks about the code

- We use [scipy's approx_fprime](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.approx_fprime.html) which basically was added for all those gradient-based optimizers in [scipy.optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html)
- As stated in the sources; i did not take care about ipopt's need for the hessian and we used ipopts [hessian-approximation](https://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node31.html)

  - the basic idea is described at [wiki: LBFGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS)
- I did ignore ipopts need for *sparsity structure of the Jacobian of the constraints*

  - a default-assumption: *the default hessian structure is of a lower triangular matrix* is used and i won't give any guarantees on what can happen here (bad performance vs. breaking everything)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I was able to get the same results as you after experimenting a bit with numdifftools and properly writing the callbacks for the gradient and Jacobian (still omitting the Hessian calculation). However, I noticed that the result is not the same as when the gradient and jacobian are explicitly calculated. I get `x=array([ 0.75487767,  0.75487765,  0.4950983 ,  0.86883695])`. I'm guessing this is a pitfall of using numerical differentiation.

Comment: That needs to be analyzed. This should not happen when there is a unique solution (which should be the case; i mentioned one possible problem and one param to tune)! People often do make mistakes when defining those. Not sure if you did, but i'm just mentioning it. Are your exit-states okay?

Comment: My output is identical to yours. The only warnings I have are related to missing libraries: `Failed to load 'libmetis.so' - using fallback AMD code`

Comment: This warning only touches performance. Well... given that info there is not much to analyze for us.

Comment: Ok, on further inspection, I had a typo in my explicit Jacobian calculation. Now I have the same result for both methods, with the expected `Objective=-0.25000000008228956` according to [this website](http://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/HockSchittkowski)

Comment: Glad to hear that! There is only one thing left: be careful with your explicit-jacobian approach when not using LBFGS! You don't need the pure jacobian, but a jacobian with some lagrange-term (according to IPOPTs docs). Now this last term is zero in many cases, but that depends on your problem (and i don't think numdifftools cares about that)!

Comment: @ sasha: could you provide some link for code showing "jacobian with some lagrange-term", please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some kind of misunderstanding about what is a mathematical function and what is its numerical implementation.

You should define your function as:

```
def func(x1, x2, x3, x4):
    return -x1*x2*x3*x4
```

Now you want to evaluate your function at specific points, which you can do using the `np.mgrid` you provided.

If you want to compute your gradient, use `copy.misc.derivative`(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html) (watch out the default parameters for dx is usually bad, change it to `1e-5`. There is no difference between linear and non-linear gradient for the numerical evaluation, only that for non linear function the gradient won't be the same everywhere.

What you did was with `np.gradient` was actually to compute the gradient from the point in your array, the definition of your function being hidden by your definition of `f`, thus not allowing for multiple gradient evaluation at different points. Also using your method makes you dependant of your discretisation step.

Comment: To my viewpoint, **derivative** takes place when having the function, but if having just an array of vars (not fitted to any function yet) we can calculate **partial derivatives** for all vars in that array, as is "from the point", that in their essence define *Jacobian (grad)*... BTW, is used to fit the func's coeffs... Thus, for any objective or any constraint to calculate the **grad** is `numerical_grad = optimize.approx_fprime(inputs0_, func, epsilon)`... and all together grads form the **Jacobian** of the System of equations (both objective & constraints)

Comment: System of equations : `jac = lambda x0, *args, **kwargs: approx_fprime(x0, fun, eps, *args, **kwargs)` ([from examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/57332/scipy.optimize.approx_fprime)) ... and testing with `np.allclose ` or `np.testing.assert_almost_equal()` rel. analytical calculations